# Should I serialize my data or create more columns for a SQL Server CE database?

Tags: sql, xml, database-design, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I'm shipping a SQL Server CE database with a Windows Phone app and I was wondering if anyone had any insight on how to store some data. I've got a ton of data stored as arrays which are attributed to other in-code objects. The arrays consist of value identifiers (integers) which correspond to an attribute for the object. For example:

**Object A**:

- AttributeSet1: [1, 3, 6, 9]
- AttributeSet2: [2, 4, 6, 8]
- AttributeDictionary: {1 : Attribute 1,
                        2 : Attribute 2,
                        3 : Attribute 3,
                        .....}

I've got hundreds of objects which have tens of attributes each. I was thinking of storing this data in one of two ways: either having multiple tables per AttributeSet where each column corresponds to an Attribute in the AttributeDictionary and each row corresponds to an Object--- OR --- Somehow store each AttributeSet as an array in a database where the columns are per Attribute set and each row is an Object. Option 1 requires creating multiple tables with multiple columns and option 2 requires one tables with a few columns but with serialized data in each. There is an XmlSerializer class for Windows Phone 8 that I can use to serialize and deserialize the data.

Which way of storing the data would be the most efficient and easiest to implement? I don't really need to be able to search through the AttributeSets so I'm thinking serializing the data then storing it in the database may be the easiest.

**TLDR: Should I store arrays associated to objects as serialized data in a database or separate the array into columns and create multiple tables?**

Any thoughts/tips?

Comment: are you sure you mean schemas and not tables? nothing in this tells me you need different schemas

Comment: Excellent reading - https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/01/21/when-should-you-store-serialized-objects-in-the-database/

Comment: From looking at how windows phone and it's App ecosystem went on, I guess it was ok that you took the easy route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

before i get long winded, let me sum it up. from your question it sounds like you know the right answer, you're just hoping someone will tell you it's ok to take the easy route. SPOILER - it's fine! but you will likely pay for it down the road.

most efficient and easiest are two very different things depending on how far out you are looking. you should be designing for well beyond initial release, i.e. respect maintainability or it will hurt later.

### in the short run

easiest is slap everything into one column that represents your full in-memory data and then just write a serialize / deserialize on an object that represents all the data. Sound like a config dump? well that's exactly what it sounds to me.

### in the long run

this is a testing / maintenance nightmare waiting to happen. IMHO you're taking the EAV (Entity Attribute Value) relational database anti-pattern to a whole new level of 'oh hell no you didnt'.
Each of these attribute sets are hopefully classes. if not then at least go with the EAV pattern. It's dirty but in your case it might just be acceptable.

The right answer can be varied but a simple explanation is, one table per class. This is effectively what entity framework does with table per hierarchy.

Personal advice - assume some day you WILL have to query the data, at least plan for it.

### so what to do

have you looked into NoSQL options, because that is probably a good fit for what you are hoping for, albeit may not be what you want long term. If not, embrace your relational sql server and give it the structure it needs to do what it is meant to do, be relational.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this is the exact answer I was looking for; some advice from someone who knows way more about databases than myself. Also, you're right I knew the right answer, but was hoping there was a better middle ground.

Comment: glad to help and been there. had to pull the plug on one project this year for this very reason, still icing my bruised ego ;)

Comment: +1 for "assume some day you WILL have to query[/update] the data, at least plan for it."  I think that's the real deal-breaker for taking the easy way out and serializing objects to the DB.

Comment: Also, as far as a "middle ground" is concerned, you could make the core relationships relational and serialize some of the minor attributes.  I've taken this approach before and haven't (yet?) run into any problems.